# How can I generate a global access token for a GCP DataPrep flow for everyone in a GCP project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, access-token, google-cloud-dataprep

In a scenario where I make a DataPrep flow, another developer would require my user-specific access token to engage it with an API call. If they made a flow, I would need their access token.

This will present an issue in the event that a developer leaves our organization and we can't call the flow that they made via API, because we would need their access token. Is there a way to generate a global access token that can be used for all DataPrep flows in a GCP project?

The GCP documentation on it is not revealing: https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Manage-API-Access-Tokens_145281444

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to give access to a group and then add each developper to that group.

In the eventuality that a developper leaves, you will only have to remove the user from the group.